# Does a rock experience its existence?

Tags: metaphysics, existence

By experience, I do not imply a subjective experience like that of an animal (with memory, decision making etc).

Could a rock, for instance, have individuated experience of its existence like a bacteria, fungus, or an RNA virus does.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100920/discussion-on-question-by-pkwssis-does-a-rock-experience-its-existence).

Answer (score 3):

SHORT ANSWER

No, by the definition of experience, rocks do not experience their existsence.

LONG ANSWER

To be clear, sometimes people see 'experience' as a synonym for 'history', which is likely a result of 'experience' being used *metaphorically* for 'history'. For example, "what did that boat experience at sea? She looks sad!" This is a form of [anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism), and as such is not literal, but poetic. If you believe in [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime), all things have a history. But literally experience is generally understood as distinct from history such that all things have a history, but only some of them experience it. To wit:

From Google:

> **ex·pe·ri·ence**
>   /ˌikˈspirēəns/
>
> noun
>       Practical contact with and observation of facts or events.
>       "he had already learned his lesson by painful experience"

Note that the plain language definition includes terms like observation, facts, and events, all of which are related to the [epistemological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) source of knowledge known as [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection) or for some [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness). Whether you lean to [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) or [empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism), the SEP entry 'consciousness' recognizes there are some widely recognized theories of consciousness:

> 9.1 Higher-order theories
>       9.2 Reflexive theories
>       9.3 Representationalist theories
>       9.4 Narrative Interpretative Theories
>       9.5 Cognitive Theories
>       9.6 Information Integration Theory
>       9.7 Neural Theories
>       9.8 Quantum theories
>       9.9 Non-physical theories

Between the advent of science and particularly psychology, in the West, experience is seen as a peculiarity of certain types of systems historically described along the [mind-body duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism). As such, the answer is no.

Comment: Well researched answer as always, but I think any answer would be insufficient given that OP hasn't even defined "experience." That, however, is not to say that your answer is wrong; In fact, in this case the question surely is. Regards